# Editing Prettier options in Vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

I need to enable .tpl files to be formatted like HTML by Prettier. 
[I've found on GitHub](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5428) this block of code who should do it  :

```
 overrides: [
 {
   files: '*.html.tpl',
   options: { parser: 'html' },
 },
],
```

How should I implement it?

Comment: Here's how you can configure your prettier :  https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, I read it and didn't understand where should I put my config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings.

In the search for box, search for "Associations" and then click on "Edit on settings.json".

Add the following to the JSON file:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.html.tpl": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options as of the syntax you want to use.

Here is an exemple in JSON:

```
//.prettierrc.json
{
  "semi": false,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.html.tpl",
      "options": { "parser": "html" },
    },
  ],
}
```

You have more exemples on the [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#configuration-overrides).