# VSCode prettier doesn't format <span> or <option> elements

Tags: html, formatting, visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier is formatting everything fine except `<span>` and `<option>` elements and it's pretty annoying. Is there some setting that can adjust this? the only settings I have for Prettier are:

```
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 500
```

---

[VSCode Prettier Format on Save messes up formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215212/vscode-prettier-format-on-save-messes-up-formatting) (Javascript issue)
[VSCODE: Prettier HTML formatting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603744/vscode-prettier-html-formatting-issue) (Different problem)
[Editing Prettier options in Vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481800/editing-prettier-options-in-vscode) (File type related)


**Screenshots:**

[image: span element doesn't format]

*span element doesn't format*

[image: Option element doesn't format]

*Option element doesn't format*

[image: Other elements format perfectly]

*Other elements format perfectly*

---

**EDIT** [Here's the link to the Prettier's Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAJgSwG4D4A6UABCaWeeagA4HEX0MkAWcATnAOQDORAhkYUZDK-GLwBGmKOjgAPALz4QABiVEwAG15cuikOJjEDUALRc4kab1YBPNawga4e8QFcYMaGvS8xJqlpgcAC2CDAuEB4Qwd6+vCaeAOaJTnpUEOnYbLF+MKyYyWx6AGYQYK5cajCYMKlK6ZnZILhcVLzEcrzBAXCC9Kit7epaOiXxXGJgANZExeOTU2bBs-EATLJKtEKomMPaukpzPHMmYJismnArZgsm65uoAPSYW4w7e6OH2tcAjq5wE0w0GuE140xMAEYNs0ni8+hQnoMoK8yE9eCjhAjHjR4ZiiE8sHhCMS6HjKOYnGAYB8DiBSqxgqdoHlHGpMOg9GB2FgYABlSDsTaEVAZarA7C8DT-PQQgDsADpZQAOTYABQgEFYRAAwtyakQABQANgAzABOIiaohOHQASieoqByOFjvFkulSghEPlABYIZsAGK8c46vXU40+5QmI1ms32x6u51QEVUMXECVS5xKI3y5QAVjUFIs8HQuAA4hr0KG4DzDbLlFHZT64w7U07aCm00QMx6QD7cyrmgBRWRBDROWDV2sG2V55QAanjiY7jyLVNohBAABoQImuMhQNYHAB3VXWBD7lCS4+8Gz7nfiVhgqZwPltM5QRLIPL-HchcQ1jI6AADLtIkri8IkcABpqwS+NUn7ICAvDuBA24gEwMDBBoADqTA1AC75wLyF41DgNQ2EhYA6OhUjmKwMCqk+iRwcgcwaOYO4AFZcLIABCT7TK+vJdHAwFSHAbGSpxIA8bIvJSCkcAAIquJEklIOxMltKw9FIeIEhwBo6FUA45g4U+VBIaZAJsFk6F-OpTEZJeyFcCYUBwDWNboewfznHATGQaxmnSXAO7mMEmDfqwv4gFwilOKp6lSRx4UgGI4g4eyMBMMgqw7nkwYaIp2rRCFIAAnm6EVHAAAqEiXlp6XYP8ACS0hhPy+SpgAgtIvIwDYTipdp+SwNl6C5cgc7KAAvnNQA) It is giving me an error that doesn't make sense to me (Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag)

---

Comment: Do you have a project specific prettier config, through the `package.json` or `.prettierrc`, that interferes with your VS Code settings?

Comment: Could you reproduce your problem on [Prettier's Playground](https://prettier.io/playground) and share a link to it here?

Comment: @thorn̈, added an edit.

Comment: @Keimeno, I have not changed the package.json or or have a prettierrc in my project

Comment: @WushuDrew the example in prettier's playground works if you wrap everything in a `<div>`

Comment: Is it possible that you have a syntax error in your code? If you change the formatting of any other element (not span or option) does it format it correctly?

Comment: @Keimeno I used https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea to make sure there were no syntax errors and changing the formatting of all other elements still format correctlu on Save. I did notice that any exclamation points  (<!-- Comment  --> or <!DOCTYPE html>) prohibit the playground from working

Comment: A document with *only* the <select><option> elements work fine, but when they're wrapped in a <div> then it doesn't work.

Comment: @WushuDrew you didn't specify the correct parser (`html`) there